# JFrog Artifactory unable to download jars from remote repository

Tags: maven, artifactory, jcenter, jfrog-cli

When I run my maven build pointing to the JFrog Artifactory setup I see the following error in the log:

```
2020-05-14T04:41:01.640Z [jfrt ] [ERROR] [dcb2a29d3c46472e] [o.a.r.RemoteRepoBase:806      ] [http- 
nio-8081-exec-1] - IO error while trying to download resource 
'jcenter:org/springframework/security/spring-security-web/4.2.2.RELEASE/spring-security-web- 
4.2.2.RELEASE.jar': **javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection reset**
2020-05-14T04:41:01.641Z [jfrt ] [WARN ] [dcb2a29d3c46472e] [o.a.e.DownloadServiceImpl:266 ] [http- 
nio-8081-exec-1] - **Sending HTTP error code 404: Connection reset**
```

I have checked the connectivity to the jcenter repo from within the Artifactory admin conosole, and its says that its able to connect.

Require your assistance.

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Please check the URL you are using for JCenter and make sure it is using secure HTTP - https://jcenter.bintray.com.
Starting in January 2020, JCenter is only serving requests made with HTTPS. From that point on, all requests made with HTTP are denied and any builds that use a JCenter URL with the non-secure HTTP protocol will fail.
For more info see the following [blog post](https://jfrog.com/blog/secure-jcenter-with-https/).